# ViewController for UIPickerView freezes after selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, uipickerview

I have a viewcontroller with UIPickerView is supposed to show images depending on the selection. My pickerview works and the images appear fine, but it freezes after the first selection is made.

Is there something I'm missing? This is the first time I've worked with a picker view.

Thanks for you help!

.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.array  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Assault",@"Support",@"Specialist", nil];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.16545 green:.16545 blue:.16545 alpha:1];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:       (NSInteger)component
{return [self.array count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
return [self.array objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
UIView *streakView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
[self.view addSubview:streakView];

NSLog(@"Selected Row %d", row);
switch(row)
{

    case 0: {
        UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
        [button1 setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button1.frame = CGRectMake(83, 275, 75, 75);
        [streakView addSubview:button1];

        UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
        [button2 setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button2.frame = CGRectMake(163, 275, 75, 75);
        [streakView addSubview:button2];


        UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIImage *btnImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
        [button3 setImage:btnImage3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button3.frame = CGRectMake(243, 275, 75, 75);
        [streakView addSubview:button3];

        break;
    }

    case 1:
        self.package.text = @"Green #00FF00";
        self.package.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green: 255.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:255.0f/255.0f];
        break;
    case 2:
        self.package.text = @"Orange #FF681F";
        self.package.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:205.0f/255.0f green:   140.0f/255.0f blue:31.0f/255.0f alpha:255.0f/255.0f];
        break;
}
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be that your streakView is covering up the picker so you can no longer make a selection. Give it a background color, and see if that's true.

Comment: Oh! That was it! I feel so silly. Thank you so much!